# Is it early to try to read Articles for an undergrad

Tags: undergraduate

As an undergrad student. I would like to read articles but i am not sure how to.
So is it early to try to read articles or how to?

Comment: Please say a bit more. What sort of "articles" are you asking about?

Comment: 1. Obtain article, usually in print or electronic form. 2. Read.

Comment: At some schools (like mine), instructors (like me) assign papers for students to write/present about in the upper-level courses. Perhaps you can see if some of your instructors will do the same in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean by "articles" research articles in published journals and the like.

In that case, it depends a lot on the field of study and where you are in your undergraduate education. For example, in math there are articles which are genuine research and could be read by any dedicated undergrad willing to put in the effort and maybe look a few terms up. This is very common in graph theory for example. But in number theory, while there are many very elementary articles, there are others which use deep, sophisticated techniques. And then you have areas like much of topology where almost any serious research article will be completely inaccessible to someone without a lot of prior training. In other fields, the situation is similar, with specific subfields ranging a lot. That said, some areas are easier to read than others. For example a lot of articles from the social sciences and humanities are easy to read if one has taken a basic introductory course in the relevant topic.

In general, if there's a specific topic that interests you, you can try to read an article and see how much work is involved in understanding it.